# Grid View Display C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm in the middle of creating a comparison website, I have a list of products which I'm displaying in a grid view, however, I want to display each row individually but not sure on how to achieve it, can anyone point in the right direction.

Below is something similar in what I want to get to. say I had 10 results then I would want to see 10 rows etc.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help, explain properly what do you mean by individually and also, post some code and where you are stuck.

Comment: What issue you are facing in using Gridview?